# Keras shared layer batch update: How are the samples mixed

Tags: keras

I'm using keras shared layer via functional API and the model.train_on_batch option, i.e.

```
dense_layer = Dense(10, name='dense_1')
out1 = dense_layer(input1)
out2 = dense_layer(input2)
model = Model(input=[input1,input2],output=[out1,out2])
...
model.train_on_batch([x1,x2],[y1,y2])
```

The question is: How are the samples (x1,y1),(x2,y2) mixed if i perform model.train_on_batch()?

Are they simply concatenated along the first axis or are they randomly mixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is, neither. With the code you posted, according to [the doc](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers):

- `x1` will be passed as the first input - `dense_layer.get_input_shape_at(0)` and result in the first output `dense_layer.get_output_at(0)`
- `x2` will be passed as the second input -
  `dense_layer.get_input_shape_at(1)` and result in the second output `dense_layer.get_output_at(1)`

Actually, as far as I can tell, this model is equivalent to training `dense_layer` with `x1` and `x2` concatenated, and a single input/output (no `input2` and `output2`)

You can model a reduction of two outputs into one with a [Merge layer](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#the-merge-layer). There are different merge modes, `concat` being one of them.